# send user to another page when device is mobile

Tags: javascript, web

i'm trying to make a system when the user device is mobile send them to a mobile page with javascript but isn't works

JavaScript code

```
let mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false ;
  if(mobile == "true"){
     window.location.assign("indexm.html");
      console.log("is " + mobile);
      
  }
  if(mobile == "false"){
      window.location.assign("https://microsft.com");
      console.log("is " + mobile);
  }
  else{
      window.location.assign("indexm.html");
      console.log("is other device"  + mobile);
  }
```

when user open the page from mobile the mobile variable is true but don't send the user to the other page

Comment: `mobile` is a boolean true/false. Not a string "true"/"false". Try using `if (mobile)` and `if (!mobile)` instead.

Comment: thank you veryyyyyyyyy much my friend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.url.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

You are checking `string` type not a `boolean`. Check `mobile === true` not `mobile === "true"`

And for improvements don't make use of `assign` to redirect the user if the device is a mobile phone. Use this instead:

```
// Behavior is just like an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');
```

Using `replace()` is better because it does not keep the original page in the session history and It simulates an `HTTP` redirect and if you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use `window.location.href`.